# Recycler view only updates when I reopen the Activity after deleting from Room Database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, adapter, android-room

I have this fragment with a Recycler view that shows content from a Room Database. In my adapter I have a ImageButton that when is clicked removes the item from the list. I can confirm that the item is removed from the database but my list is not having the expected behavior. In order to it to be updated I have to open the activity again.

### Recycler View

```
public class WishlistFragment extends Fragment {
        private static WishlistAdapter mAdapter;
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        protected static List<String> wishlist;
        private Context context;
        protected static OnRestaurantClickedListener listener;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

        public static WishlistAdapter getmAdapter() {
            return mAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            context = getContext();
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            wishlist = new ArrayList<>();
            mAdapter = new WishlistAdapter(context, wishlist,getActivity(),mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            LoadWishlistTask lwt=new LoadWishlistTask(getActivity(),wishlist,mAdapter,mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            lwt.execute();

        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restaurants_list, container, false);
            mRecyclerView = mContentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContentView.getContext()));
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

            return mContentView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            try {
                listener = (OnRestaurantClickedListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnRestaurantClickedClicked");
            }
        }
}
```

### Adapter

```
public class WishlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WishlistAdapter.WishlistViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mRestaurantIds;
    private Activity act;
    private String currentUserId;

    public WishlistAdapter(Context context, List<String> ids,Activity activity,String currentUser) {
        mRestaurantIds=ids;
        mContext = context;
        act=activity;
        currentUserId=currentUser;

    }

    @Override
    public WishlistViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Get layout inflater from context
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate layout
        View rView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_restaurant, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        return new WishlistViewHolder(rView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final WishlistViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        final String id = mRestaurantIds.get(position);

        getApi().getRestaurantDetails(Integer.parseInt(id), "75be9f9e2239fe637bf9cb1b46979d91")
                .enqueue(new Callback<Restaurant_>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Restaurant_> call, Response<Restaurant_> response) {
                        final TextView name=viewHolder.nameTextView;
                        name.setText(response.body().getName());
                        final TextView rating=viewHolder.ratingTextView;
                        rating.setText(response.body().getUserRating().getAggregateRating());
                        final ImageButton remove=viewHolder.removeButton;
                        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Wishlist deletedRestaurant=new Wishlist(currentUserId,id);
                                RemoveWLTask rt=new RemoveWLTask(deletedRestaurant,act,WishlistFragment.wishlist);
                                rt.execute();
                            }
                        });

                        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                WishlistFragment.listener.onRestaurantClicked(id);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Restaurant_> call, Throwable t) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
                        builder.setMessage("Couldn´t load restaurant details");
                        AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
                        mDialog.show();
                    }
                });

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRestaurantIds.size();
    }

    private Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    private ZomatoApi getApi() {
        return getRetrofit().create(ZomatoApi.class);
    }


    public class WishlistViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView nameTextView;
        public TextView ratingTextView;
        public TextView distanceTextView;
        public ImageButton removeButton;

        public WishlistViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantName);
            ratingTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantRating);
            distanceTextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantDistance);
            removeButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.wishlistButton);


        }

    }

}
```

### Remove Task

```
public class RemoveWLTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private Wishlist deletedRestaurant;
    private DB db;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<String> wishlist;

    public  RemoveWLTask (Wishlist deletedRestaurant, Activity activity,List<String> wishlist) {
        this.deletedRestaurant=deletedRestaurant;
        this.activity=activity;
        this.db= Room.databaseBuilder(activity.getApplicationContext(), DB.class, "sample-db").build();
        this.wishlist=wishlist;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        while (!isCancelled()){
            db.daoAcess().deleteFromWishlist(deletedRestaurant);
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Void aVoid) {

        int index = wishlist.indexOf(deletedRestaurant);
        wishlist.remove(deletedRestaurant);
        WishlistFragment.getmAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(index);
        WishlistFragment.getmAdapter().notifyItemRangeChanged(index, wishlist.size());

    }
}
```

Comment: onClick of your remove button your deleting the item from the Room DB but your not remove the item from your adapter nor notifying the data set change. You must do this or your recyclerview will not show any updated data forcing you to reload the view (gets all new data from room db again missing the deleted item)

Comment: actually the problem was the argument

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, I need to pass deletedRestaurant.getRestaurantId() as argument instead of deletedRestaurant